# Badge count option in amazon SNS

Tags: node.js, amazon-sns, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I need to get badge count in my application. I am using amazon SNS service. Here is my code

```
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: 'XXXXXXX',
  secretAccessKey: 'XXXXXXX'
})
AWS.config.update({ region: 'XXXXXXX' })
const sns = new AWS.SNS()
const params = {
  PlatformApplicationArn: 'XXXXXXX',
  Token: deviceToken
}
sns.createPlatformEndpoint(params, (err, EndPointResult) => {
  const client_arn = EndPointResult["EndpointArn"];
    sns.publish({
      TargetArn: client_arn,
      Message: message,
      Subject: title,
      // badge: 1
    }, (err, data) => {
    })
  })
```

I need to know where I can add `badge` option here?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3):

We can send `json` message to AWS SNS to send push notification to application endpoint. Which allows us to send platform (APNS, FCM etc) specific fields and customizations.

Example json message for APNS is,

```
{
"aps": {
    "alert": {
        "body": "The text of the alert message"
    },
    "badge": 1,
    "sound": "default"
 }
}
```

This is how you can send request,

```
   var sns = new AWS.SNS();
   var payload = {
      default: 'This is the default message which must be present when publishing a message to a topic. The default message will only be used if a message is not present for 
  one of the notification platforms.',
      APNS: {
        aps: {
          alert: 'The text of the alert message',
          badge: 1,
          sound: 'default'
        }
      }
    };

    // stringify inner json object
    payload.APNS = JSON.stringify(payload.APNS);
    // then stringify the entire message payload
    payload = JSON.stringify(payload);

    sns.publish({
      Message: payload,      // This is Required
      MessageStructure: 'json',
      TargetArn: {{TargetArn}} // This Required
    }, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err.stack);
        return;
      }
    });
  });
```

If you need to support multiple platforms then as per AWS docs,

> To send a message to an app installed on devices for multiple platforms, such as FCM and APNS, you must first subscribe the mobile endpoints to a topic in Amazon SNS and then publish the message to the **topic**.

APNS specific payload keys can be found [APNS Payload Key Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/PayloadKeyReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH17-SW1).

AWS SNS documentation can be found here [Send Custom, Platform-Specific Payloads to Mobile Devices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-send-custommessage.html)